# Storing timestamp in PostgreSQL gives an error: "cannot cast type bigint to timestamp without time zone"

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I've created my table with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE "STORES" (
        "STOREGLOBALID"         SERIAL NOT NULL ,
        "STOREUPDATEDATETIME"   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        "CHAINID"               BIGINT ,
        "CHAINNAME"             VARCHAR(50) ,
        "SUBCHAINID"            SMALLINT ,
        "SUBCHAINNAME"          VARCHAR(50) ,
        "STOREID"               SMALLINT ,
        "STORENAME"             VARCHAR(50) ,
        "STORETYPE"             SMALLINT ,
        "ADDRESS"               VARCHAR(50) ,
        "CITY"                  VARCHAR(50) ,
        PRIMARY KEY ("STOREGLOBALID")
);
```

When I try to insert timestamp by using the following SQL for preparing statement:

```
 INSERT INTO  "STORES" 
            ("STOREGLOBALID",
            "STOREUPDATEDATETIME",
            "CHAINID",
            "CHAINNAME",
            "SUBCHAINID",
            "SUBCHAINNAME",
            "STOREID",
            "STORENAME",
            "STORETYPE",
            "ADDRESS",
            "CITY") 
            VALUES (DEFAULT, cast(? as timestamp), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And the following Java code:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setLong(1, store.getChainId());
ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(1000000000)); //this value is only for test purposes, actual value gives the same error
```

I get the following error:

> cannot cast type bigint to timestamp without time zone   Position: 235

I understand that I need to provide a timestamp, but when I do it as following:

```
ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(1000000000), Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

I get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of your prepared statement is used in

```
cast(? as timestamp)
```

and the result is stored in `STOREUPDATEDATETIME`, of type TIMESTAMP. And you're passing a long (`store.getChainId()`) as argument. So you're trying to cast a long to a timestamp.

The second argument of your prepared statement is stored in `CHAINID`, of type BIGINT. And you're passing a Timestamp as argument (`new Timestamp(1000000000)`). So PostgreSQL tries to transform this timestamp into a bigint.

The SQL should be

```
INSERT INTO  "STORES" 
        ("STOREGLOBALID",
        "STOREUPDATEDATETIME",
        "CHAINID",
        "CHAINNAME",
        "SUBCHAINID",
        "SUBCHAINNAME",
        "STOREID",
        "STORENAME",
        "STORETYPE",
        "ADDRESS",
        "CITY") 
        VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And the Java should be

```
ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(1000000000));
ps.setLong(2, store.getChainId());
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll be able to accept your answer in a 7 minutes only. It proves that sometimes it requires another pair of eyes to look at the code.